# how get datagrdiviewComboboxColumn value member?

Tags: c#

i have a small project in c#, in one of my forms i have a datagridview with 3 columns one of the columns is comboboxcolumn that bind with a sql server table id and name, i want to insert the datagridview values into another table in the comboboxcolumn i want to insert the id not a name, anyone can tel me how to do that please? this is my insert code
`

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_student.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
   sc.add_student(dgv_student.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
   Convert.ToInt32(dgv_student.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value),
   dgv_student.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
  }
```

`
the cell[1] the the combobox that display a name not the id.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have :

```
 Name  ID
 X     X
```

As your database set. When you are getting this from your database you're probably doing  :

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = GetAllFromMyDatabase(); // Select * from stuff
myDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Giving you all three columns, and the value. Now, if you want to insert only one column, why not just filter the data you're getting from your database/gridview ?

```
myComboBox.DataSource = GetOnlyIDFromMyDatabaseOrMyDataGrid(); // Select ID from Stuff
myComboBox.DataBind();
```

If you're binding your asp.net control with only the data you need, rather than getting everything and then filter, you will have less overhead to think about.

Comment: in database table i have only two columns name and id, in the combobox column i display the display member which is the name, but when i insert the datagrdiview rows into another table i want to insert the value member of th combo column cuz there is relationship between the tow tables.

Comment: @honar.cs Exactly. You have to bind your different controls with the data you want. Use a list, a dictionnary or a function filled correctly depending on your control and you're good to go.